# How do I tell a .py script to look for folders and file in the directory it is in?

Tags: python, netlify

I have a .py script that pulls in data from Google Sheets and outputs it in a yaml format. This is for my Hugo powered website which is served via Netlify. As I understand it, Netlify is capable of running Python too so I thought I could upload the web content and the python file in the same directory. This is required for updating the content dynamically, and I expect the python file to run everytime I trigger a build for the website. However, the python file requires certain credentials to work.

My code currently looks like this:

```py
# Set location to write new files to.
outputpath = Path("D:/content/submission/")

#Read JSON: 
json = Path("D:/credentials.json")
```

These are hardcoded local paths. When I bundle the script in the website directory, what paths should I write in so that when the script runs, these files are read in and outputted correctly?

I would want to output in my `content/submission` folder and read in from my `creds/credentials.json`. Should I just put these paths in? Will it know that it has to look within the directory for these folders, or is there something I need to add to the script that tells it to work within the directory it is sitting in?

Comment: Try printing `__file__` and you will have an idea.

Comment: Netlify also has environment variables where you should set credentials for use in your build process. It's also safer this way since your credentials aren't in version control or hardcorded in any of your files. https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/

Comment: @S.Ramjit I'm actually _supposed_ to be doing this, but I don't have any clue as to how I should read those credentials since the environment variable file is a `.toml` and what Google gives me a is .json. If you have anything that you could refer me to so that I lose `credentials.json` ( I realize how bad an idea this is), I would be very grateful.

Comment: The simpler way would be to copy _the entire JSON_ and paste it in as a one big string and give it a name then parse the JSON in whatever you're using: https://community.netlify.com/t/how-to-handle-credentials-files-securely-in-netlify-functions/7572. The other (proper) way: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/netlify-functions-firebase-and-graphql-working-together-at-last/ and the source for that last link: https://github.com/JeffML/firebase-lambda2

Comment: The `.toml` file isn't your environment variable. Its a configuration file that netlify uses to know what to do with your build. You could declare environment vars in there but I'd advise using the WebGUI to put in credentials https://app.netlify.com/sites/*yoursitenamehere*/settings/deploys > Environment

Answer (score 2):

First, credentials and secrets are best kept out of files (and esp, esp,  source control).

For general file locations however, you can use something like:

```
pa_same_but_json = Path(__file__).with_suffix(".json")
pa_same_directory = Path(__file__).parent / "nosecrets.json")
```

To answer your comments:

(Mind you not 100% sure about Window Drives in the following):

#### `parent`

is an attribute on Path objects allowing you to "climb up" hierarchy.

`Path("c:\temp\foo.json").parent` returns same as  `Path("c:\temp")`

Yes, you can do `mypath.parent.parent`

#### `/` is a path concatenation operator

**when applied to Path objects**

So

`myfile = os.path.join(["c:", "temp", "foo.json"])`

and

`myfile_as_a_Path = Path("c:") / "temp" / "foo.json"`

are the same, except for one being a string, the other a Path instance.  Once the first Path has been built (on C:) the rest of the code "knows that it operating on Path instances" and re-purposes the division operator support (probably some magic `__div__` method intended for instance math ) to support path concatenation.  This happens because most operations on Path instances return another Path, allowing you to do this type of chaining.

It's best not to write way up the hierarchy in a hosted/VM context (you never know directory structure above or if you have permissions), but something based on your script location might be

```
pa_current = Path(__file__).parent

# could `content/submission` but that's assuming you're always on Posix
# systems.  Letting Pathlib do the work is safer, even if Windows probably
# puts up with `/`
pa_write = pa_current / "content" / "submission" 

pa_read = pa_current / "credentials.json"
```

These at this points are Path instances, but really not much different than strings except having smarter methods to manipulate them.  **They don't know or care if the files exist or not.**

#### P.S.

A consideration is that, in many web contexts, writing to code directories (like what happens in a content/submission **under** the python scripts) is a security goof as well.

Maybe `pa_write = pa_current.parent.parent / "uploads" / "content" / "submission"` would be better.

Specifically when it comes to user uploads and secrets, please refer to best practices for your platform, not just what Python can do.  This answer was about pathlib.Path, not Hugo uploads.

Comment: Thank you! As an above comment  noted, I was confusing the Netlify build variables with the config file. Silly but its my first time :P What does `parent /` in your code mean? Could you provide an example with `/content/colorrun/` this file path, given that the `.py` is in the root folder?

Comment: Something like this: `outputpath = Path(__file__).parent("/content/submission/")`?